# imfreehand data type issue

Tags: matlab, region, roi

I'm using `imfreehand` in my program, and when I came to `erosion`, I got the following error (I didn't paste the whole error):

```
Error using imerode
Expected input number 1, IM, to be one of these types:

numeric, logical

Instead its type was imfreehand.
```

It seems then that the region I extract will be of type `imfreehand`? Is there a way to convert to the above data types? Or, there is some way to deal with such issue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a  look at the examples in [this](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/22883) post. My interpretation is that you create a mask using the handle associated with the generated freehand object,

```
hFH = imfreehand();
binaryImage = hFH.createMask();
```

then use the mask for additional purposes.